# conflict 'this' references of child and parent components

Tags: reactjs

I have also mentioned the issue in code block as comments, I have a child component(Comments) contains form element, when it submit I call "SaveComment()" method of parent component, but this cause conflict of "this" reference..

```
class VideoDetail extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.appState=this.props.appState
    debugger//here this.appState is correctly defined
  }
    SaveComment(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.appState.comment.name = this.name.value;
      //this.appState is undefined since "this" keywords refers to 'Comments' child component 
      //How can I both use my parent "this" object and a reference object that can get values form child component like here;"this.name.value"
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div className="show-top-grids">
            <Comments {...{totalCommentCount:"12345",bok:"boook!", SaveComment:this.SaveComment}}/>
      </div>
        )
    }
}

const Comments = (commentContext)=>{
  return (
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>{commentContext.SaveComment(e)}}>
          <input type="text" ref={(input)=>{this.name=input}} placeholder="Name" required=" " />                                           
          <input type="submit" defaultValue="SEND" />
          <div className="clearfix"> </div>
        </form>
  )
}
```

How can I fix it or change my way to handle it ?

Comment: Try binding `SaveComment` method using arrow function like this ` SaveComment = (e) => {`

Comment: Where will i type this exactly I use af inside child componemt already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you would get a error on the console when this executes `ref={(input)=>{this.name=input}}`.

To access state or prop, you need to have access to their context. So when your function is declared you have to bind. The easiest way is to use `arrow` functions. So in `VideoDetail` your `SaveComment` will look like

```
  SaveComment = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // your other logic
  }
```

Since one cannot use `ref` in function components, you can convert the `Comments` function component to a class that extends `React.Component`. This way you can set ref. If you prefer to follow this path then your `Comments` would look like

```
class Comments extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>{this.props.SaveComment(e)}}>
          <input type="text" ref={(input)=>{this.name=input}} placeholder="Name" required=" " />                                           
          <input type="submit" defaultValue="SEND" />
          <div className="clearfix"> </div>
        </form>);
  }
 }
```

In the above method to access the form values in your `VideoDetail`, you can pass the data from the `Comments`. So your `Comments` component will look like

```
class Comments extends Component {
  onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const formData = {
     name: this.name.value,
   };
   this.props.SaveComment(formData);
  }

  render() {
   return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="text" ref={(input)=>{this.name=input}} placeholder="Name" required=" " />                                           
          <input type="submit" defaultValue="SEND" />
          <div className="clearfix"> </div>
        </form>);
  }
 }
```

The above way, you can add as many data as you need in formData and send it back to the parent. And your `SaveComment` in `VideoDetail` will transform to

```
 SaveComment = (formData) => {
   // use formData as you wish
 }
```

Comment: I will accept it since i solved this with your recommendation but "functional components cannot have ref" is wrong idea :)

Answer (score 3):

There're 2 things to resolve from the above snippet:

1. How to ensure `this` refers to the parent instance in event callback
2. How to pass form values from child to parent.

To "lock" `this` keyword, [handling events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) recommends either: a) bind this keyword in constructor b) using [property initializer syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) , so that you don't lose the context of "this".

To pass form value to parent, you simply need to change the argument of `SaveComment(e)` -> `SaveComment(comment)` in `<VideoDetail />`, and in the `<Comment />`, change `onSubmit={(e)=>{commentContext.SaveComment(e)}` -> `onSubmit={(e)=>{commentContext.SaveComment(this.name)}`.

In summary, React embraces uni-directional data flow, parent pass `props` to children and children takes `(state, props) => UI` to render. If children want to send information back, typically its done through passing arguments to parent's callbacks, so that data still flows in one-way and thus a good separation between Parent & Child regarding data.

Comment: 1) "SaveComment(e) -> SaveComment(comment) " what do you mean just changing name of parameter makes the magic here? it didnt. 
2) I cant post only one field, whatif i have many input fields at the form of child, would you suggest change it to onSubmit={(e)=>{commentContext.SaveComment(this.name,this.surname,this.email.. etc) Your describe makes sense clearly but answer not

Comment: how to bind this keyword at parent? Its also not recommended send databack to parent i searched probaby i will change it good

Comment: Your `SaveComment` is a customized callback function, you can pass any arguments as you want, you decide when to call it. While `onSubmit` is a Synthetic Event handler react passes `event` as argument and takes charge of firing event for you in response to user actions.

Comment: If you want to pass multiple form values, simple wrap them into plain object `SaveComment({ val1, val2, val3 })`, and you can do sth like this as well `onSubmit={(e) => { var valuesFromEvent = e.target......; this.props.SaveComment(valuesFromEvent) }}`, SaveComment is simply a callback passed down as props,  NOT strictly an event handler.